# What's the difference between these two import syntaxes in python?

Tags: python

```
~/
    A/
        __init__.py
        a1.py
        a2.py
```

a1.py:

```
from a2 import y
```

a2.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/shellfly/')
from A import a1  # raise ImportError
from A.a1 import c # normal
```

What's the difference between:

```
 from PACKAGE import MODULE
```

and

```
 from MODULE import VAR"
```

and why did the above import expression throw an exception?

I got this exception in Django, which A is an app folder, so it is already in PYTHONPATH,
and I have add my work directory to my test my code

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong here, but `from A import a1` would not raise an error here.

Comment: Can we have the exception traceback?

Comment: Isn't this a circular-import problem? `a1` imports something from `a2` but `a2` tries to import `a1`.

Answer (score 0):

`from A import a1` is still inside the `A` folder. `a2.py` will expect it to be `/A/A/a1.py`

Eclipse throws the error; `unresolved import a2`, as it's not in the file's absolute path.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on whether OP has added the parent directory to his Python path or not. Absolute imports should then work OK.